# How to access a Data class instance in another activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, instance-variables

I would like to create a data class instance inside of my `PlayerDetails.kt` activity and then be able to access its data in another activity later on.

I'm doing this because I don't want to constantly keep passing the data between activities using `Intent.putString`, `Intent.putInt` or Shared Preferences as the data is only useful for the current session. I just want to retrieve the data on demand whenever I like here.

**PlayerDetails.kt**

```
class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...
    val player1 = Player(name="james", age=23, gender="male")
    val player2 = Player(name="sophie", age=38, gender="female")
}
```

**Player.kt**

```
data class Player (
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val gender: String
)
```

As I've got multiple Player's, is it possible to create multiple `Player` instances in `PlayerDetails.kt` and be able to access those individually in a later activity?

Comment: If this is what you need, without copying to intent and stuff, then you shouldn't be using multiple Activities for this.

Comment: Also, please be aware of your application's behavior in case of low memory condition. Intents are kept alive by the system for your application's session if it's terminated by low memory condition then restarted from launcher; while a singleton will just be cleared out and nulled and your app will crash when restarted because it finds unexpected nulls.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm doing this because I don't want to constantly keep passing the data between activities using Intent.putString, Intent.putInt or Shared Preferences as the data is only useful for the current session.

You sound like you want to have your cake and eat it too; which is a problem because if you don't use Intent bundle, and you don't use disk persistence; then you'll still at least need to implement `BaseActivity.onSaveInstanceState()` otherwise your poor user will lose their data (state) when they return to your app after some time ;)

Imagine this, you set the fields in Activity1, I go over to Activity3, then receive a phone call that takes 20 minutes. In the meantime Android terminates my app, I come back from the phone call, the app starts from scratch at Activity3, and the stuff I had supposedly set in Activity1 but never saved out in any way is now `null` or `""` or `0`. Not very good UX, especially when it causes crashes, too.

---

The simple solution for your scenario is to instead of decomposing your `Player` by hand each time, just use `@Parcelize`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Then

```
@Parcelize data class Player: Parcelable (
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val gender: String
)
```

And

```
// inline fun <reified T: Activity> Activity.intentFor(builder: Intent.() -> Unit) {
//     return Intent(this, T::class.java).apply(builder)
// }

startActivity(intentFor<OtherActivity>() {
    putParcelableExtra("player", player)
})

val player = intent.getParcelableExtra("player")
```